# FormView dynamic templates does not send form values on insert/updates

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, formview

I am getting following error when I click Insert button on a dynamically loaded templates for FormView. The default form mode is set to insert. I do see insert template loading fine. I have TypeName="WebApplication1.Repository.AccountRepo" and DataObjectTypeName="WebApplication1.Model.Account" to correct types. Can someone please help.

The error I get is
**ObjectDataSource 'ObjectDataSource1' has no values to insert. Check that the 'values' dictionary contains values.**

```
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <h2>
            Welcome to ASP.NET!
        </h2>
        <p>
            To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">
                www.asp.net</a>.
        </p>
        <p>
            You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
                title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
            <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
        </p>
        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
            OnLoad="FormView1_Load" OnModeChanged="FormView1_ModeChanged" 
            oninit="FormView1_Init" ViewStateMode="Enabled"  DefaultMode="Insert">

        </asp:FormView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="WebApplication1.Model.Account"
            DeleteMethod="Delete"  SelectMethod="Select" TypeName="WebApplication1.Repository.AccountRepo"
            UpdateMethod="Update" oninserting="ObjectDataSource1_Inserting"
            InsertMethod="Insert">
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="acct" Type="Object" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="acct" Type="Object"/>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </asp:Content>
```

Following code in page init method

```
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ITemplate control = Page.LoadTemplate("~/WebUserControl2.ascx");
            FormView1.EditItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("~/WebUserControl2.ascx");
            FormView1.InsertItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("~/WebUserControl2.ascx");
            FormView1.ItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("~/WebUserControl2.ascx");

        }
    }
```

I have following HTML fragments in WebUserControl2.ascx

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl2.ascx.cs"
        Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl2" ViewStateMode="Enabled" %>
    Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
    <br />
    Address:
    <asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
    <br />

    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert"
        Text="Insert" />
    &nbsp;
    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
```

This is the sample repository class that is business class set to ObjectDataSource1

```
    public class AccountRepo
    {
        private static Model.Account _account;
        public void Delete(Model.Account acct)
        {
            _account = new Model.Account();
        }

        public Model.Account Update(Model.Account acct)
        {
            _account = acct;
            return _account;
        }

        public Model.Account Insert(Model.Account acct)
        {
            _account = new Model.Account() { Name = "new" };
            return _account;
        }

        public Model.Account Select()
        {
            if (_account == null)
                _account = new Model.Account() { Name = "BrandNew" };

            return _account;
        }

    }
```

This is the account class

```
    public class Account
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address {get;set;}

        public static Account CreateAccount(){
            return new Account();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I *feel* like there is something wrong in with `InsertParameters`, but I'm having terouble putting my finger on what.  How does your code know what "acct" is?

Comment: It is the parameter name of Insert and Update method.

Comment: But, If I were to take the WebUserControl2.ascx content and place it in 
<asp:FormView>
 <ItemTemplate> <!-- Place it here -->
 <ItemTemplate>
 <InsertTemplate> <!-- And place it here -->
 </InsertTemplate>
</asp:FormView> It works with no error, only when loading the templates dynamically it some how not able to create formvalue collections?

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting detail. Yeah, I've never tried loading the templates that way.

Comment: I saw this question http://forums.asp.net/t/1069339.aspx and looks like the dude ran into same problem as mine, back 5 years ago, looks like no response to his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution on this page. Do what the author suggest and it works.
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4721/dynamically-loading-an-ibindabletemplate/